# React App not redirecting properly on AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

This is my first time deploying a react app on AWS Amplify. The app works fine as a SPA, the only problem is re-directions.

For example; when a user completely signs up and gets a link to verify email, clicking on the link redirects me to mydomain.com/index.html.

Also when i try navigating to mydomain.com/sign-in (which should lead me to sign in page), it redirects me to mydomain.com/index.html.

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 16):

Try going to App settings->Rewrites and redirects

Add in a new rule

- Source should be `</^((?!\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf)$).)*$/>`
- Target address `/index.html`
- Type `200 (Rewrite)`

Here's an example of what the end result should look like.

[image: Example image]

If that doesn't work, try this one

`</^((?!.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf)$).)*$/>`

Comment: It works, thank you!. Is the regex matching ALL files, or only the extensions that you've specified? Also, can you please elaborate on why we need to do this?

Comment: @oyalhi not sure tbh. I read this from an aws engineer on github

Comment: I also had this problem and resolved by just changing 404 (Redirect)  to 404 (Rewrite). followed this: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/59

Works at all? Someone knows the difference from this to the answer?

Answer (score 5):

You need to accept and route all files. When react builds, it runs off the `index` file, but react-router manipulates the path as SPA requirements have it. 
Paste this into your rewrites and redirects. This will generally work if you are running a standard react router webapp.

```
[
    {
        "source": "</^((?!\\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf)$).)*$/>",
        "target": "/index.html",
        "status": "200",
        "condition": null
    },
    {
        "source": "/<*>",
        "target": "/",
        "status": "404",
        "condition": null
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the steps above don't fully work try adding `<base href="/" />` to the `<head/>` section of your index.html as mentioned [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/59#issuecomment-632988536).

This is my final Rewrites and redirects opened in the text editor:

```json
[
    {
        "source": "https://example.com",
        "target": "https://www.example.com",
        "status": "302",
        "condition": null
    },
    {
        "source": "</^[^.]+$|\\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|map|json|webp|html|xml|webmanifest|mp4)$)([^.]+$)/>",
        "target": "/index.html",
        "status": "200",
        "condition": null
    },
    {
        "source": "/<*>",
        "target": "/index.html",
        "status": "404-200",
        "condition": null
    }
]
```